# Alembic version table in a separate schemas

Tags: python-3.x, alembic

I have 100s of alembic version tables for different applications in postgres. Some of the applications use different username for migrations and its possible to set `search_path` in postgres for those application migrations. Based on the database username, due to search_path, the version tables are created in different postgres schemas. Some of the applications use common username and end up having version table name conflict in public schema as they do not have search_path set to specific schema. How do i enable alembic to use a specific postgres schema to create the version table?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Alembic `EnvironmentContext.configure` method takes an argument `version_table_schema` which allows you to specify the schema to put the version table in. ([Docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure))

For example in your `env.py`

```
from alembic import context
...

def run_migrations_online():
    connectable = config.attributes.get('connection', None)
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            version_table='alembic_version',
            version_table_schema="my_schema",  # <-- Set the schema name here
        )
    ...
```